# It's in my inventory, but not in my area (Curious, a long-awaited badge)

Tags: support, badges

> Okay, my title is awkwardly long, but let's not speak of that.

Ever since I reached a good amount of support in Arqade, there has been a badge I've been wanting to get, but due to certain circumstances, it's a bit hard to get. The [**Curious**](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/badges/286/curious) badge has been a very big accomplishment ever since I first joined Stack Exchange.

Back then, I asked [this question](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15544/the-curious-badge-and-timezones) (which is still on the Featured on Meta page during this time) where I wondered that in my 5 days of asking, why haven't I got the amount of days needed. And after some time, I got the long-awaited badge.

But, wait? Where is it? I finally received it and it is not visible.
[image: My Badge Count]

If I got the badge, then my bronze badge count should've incremented by 1, but nooooo, it remained the same.

If you take a look at my badge section:
[image: Badge Section]

It should be there, it is not visible.

Now look at my actual inventory:
[image: My Badges]

It's right there, and I'm wondering when will it appear. It's been hours since I received it, and still not there.

Why is this so?

Comment: I feel like my title has some WilburSoot reference.

Comment: Assuming [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/381732/can-you-subtract-time) (asked 15h ago) is the one that got you over the line for the Curious requirements, then you should probably [blame caching](https://shouldiblamecaching.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's there now:

[image]

What Robotnik says: blame caching. Some information is updated real-time (especially when you're tracking it), some is not. This is confusing many users, hence I started an [FAQ answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/298953/295232) about it:

> #### Why didn't I get badge name right now?
>
> (even though the badge progress tracker on my user profile or the review stats page indicates that I qualify for the badge; I even got the message "Congratulations - you earned [badge name]")
>
> ...
>
> Note that the badge tracker display in the public profile is loaded live, so it may display a "Congratulations - you've earned [badge]" message before the badge script has run and actually awarded you the badge. That message is simply based on full, live progress to earn the badge, and not based on whether the badge was actually awarded to you or not. Only when you see the badge in the "Badges" subtab of your user profile is when the badge has actually been awarded to you.